# How can i install Adobe Air on Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, air, adb, genymotion, android-package-managers

I'm trying to install Adobe Air (com.adobe.air) in a Genymotion emulator emulating a Galaxy S4 with android 4.4.4 and I am getting:

```
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]
```

With adb logcat I can see:

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 2350):
D/AndroidRuntime( 2350): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 2350): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm( 2350): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2350): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2350): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2350): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 2350): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 2350): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
E/memtrack( 2350): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 2350): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 2350): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
W/ActivityManager(  517): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Adobe.AIR.v16.0.0.259_www.revdl.com.apk
W/ActivityManager(  517): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Adobe.AIR.v16.0.0.259_www.revdl.com.apk
I/PackageManager(  517): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl1421280503
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1626K, 20% free 10767K/13324K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 309K, 17% free 11063K/13324K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1138K, 17% free 11163K/13324K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1036K, 17% free 11173K/13324K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 996K, 17% free 11171K/13324K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 985K, 17% free 11176K/13324K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 987K, 17% free 11184K/13324K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
D/xmlCheckExt(  517): <filter>
D/xmlCheckExt(  517):  pkgName = org.mozilla.firefox
D/xmlCheckExt(  517): <filter>
D/xmlCheckExt(  517):  pkgName = org.mozilla.firefox_beta
D/xmlCheckExt(  517): <filter>
D/xmlCheckExt(  517):  pkgName = com.good.android.gfe
D/xmlCheckExt(  517): <filter>
D/xmlCheckExt(  517):  pkgName = com.adobe.air
I/PackageManager(  517): Package with second ABI is in black list: 10079com.adobe.air
W/PackageManager(  517): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.adobe.air-1.apk
D/dalvikvm(  517): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1038K, 17% free 11162K/13324K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 12ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 2350): Shutting down VM
```

I noted the following piece in the log:

```
D/xmlCheckExt(  517):  pkgName = com.adobe.air
I/PackageManager(  517): Package with second ABI is in black list: 10079com.adobe.air
```

But when I try:

```
adb shell pm unblock com.adobe.air
```

I'm getting:

```
Package com.adobe.air new blocked state: true
```

How can I unblock / remove from the blacklist Adobe Air package?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could find the apk in the sdk folder. In mac is here:

```
/Applications/Research In Motion/blackberry-tablet-sdk-3.2.1/runtimes/air
```